# Device error: WARNING: unexpected '-prop' value ('emu.uuid=520cf82a-fcb6-4b6a-b5c4-386e635c8ba6'), only 'qemu.*' properties are supported

Tags: android, xamarin

Getting this error whenever I am trying to start my emulator from android device manager. Any solution ?
[image]

Comment: Please check your PC and VS version. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-manager?tabs=windows&pivots=windows And do you use the Hyper-V? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows If you set all the seetings, please try to reinstall the SDKs.

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: Any news on the issue ?

Comment: Were you able fix this issue? I'm having the same issue even in VS 2019 - 16.8.6

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: After some additional trial and error on this subject, I've learned for AMD I needed to turn off "Windows Sandbox" from Windows Features with referencing the image below. So I can keep "Hyper-V", "Windows Hypervisor Platform", and "Virtual Machine Platform" on.

Now, if you have an emulator like [NoxPlayer](https://www.bignox.com/), then you'll need to turn off all the settings mentioned below as emulators like Nox conflicts with Hyper-V.

---

**ORIGINAL**: For AMD, I found out from [Google's Android Emulator Hypervisor repo for AMD](https://github.com/google/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for-amd-processors) that states:

> Prerequisite:
>
> 1. CPU has virtualization extension and BIOS has NOT disabled the extension.
> 2. Hyper-V must be disabled. Refer to [this page](https://github.com/google/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for-amd-processors/wiki/Is-Hyper-V-really-disabled%3F) for more information.

Turning off Hyper-V did the trick for me after trying to reinstall the SDKs.

> Hyper-V must be disabled to use the Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver
> for AMD Processors. However, unchecking "Hyper-V" in Windows Features
> Dialog might not guarantee that Hyper-V is disabled. Quite a few
> features in Windows 10 will enable Hyper-V implicitly. Users may not
> even know Hyper-V is activated when they enable one of these features.
>
> To our best knowledge, these includes Virtual Machine Platform,
> Windows Hypervisor Platform, Windows Sandbox, Core Isolation,
> Credential Guard. Additionally, Windows Subsystem for Linux version 2
> requires Virtual Machine Platform, meaning that it implicitly requires Hyper-V.

The picture below was taken straight from the repo's wiki.

[image: Windows features: How to turn off Hyper-V]